# How to change target sdk and compile sdk into 25

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I recently updated my android studio in **2.3** . Now I want to change my target sdk and compile sdk into api `25` but which dependency should I compile ? now my target sdk and compile sdk is api `23` and I am compiling the dependency `23.4.0`

Thankz in advance

my gradle file

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.application"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 60
    versionName "2.2.6.25"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
 }
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:design:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0',
        'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: can you post your gradle , Mainly the dependencies part

Comment: Here is step by step tutorial [link](http://abhiandroid.com/androidstudio/change-api-sdk-level-android-studio.html)

Comment: @bdevloper I have already gone through the link you suggested but no use :-(

Comment: @OmarHossamEldin please wait for a while i gonna edit my question by adding the gradle

Answer (score 3):

Call **:25.1.0** instead of **:23.4.0**

You should use

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
```

and

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
```

Comment: `25.1.0` right ?  and what about `com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0` ?

Comment: Why making it more and more confusing when you can do this using AS's UI?

Comment: @Androbot you can set `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'`

Comment: May be 25.2.0 would be better and google play services 10.2.0

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti sir, Agree

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your project Structure
2. Then click on app module
3. Now click on Flavors
4. There you Edit your Target sdk version and Min sdk version

[please check screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MUTZ.png)

Comment: This is better way than to go into code, where you can easily write the incorrect version of `buildToolsVersion`, since it updates often.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 25
  buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 25
  }
}
```

Comment: Do this in build.gradle file @Androbot